# What is wrong with this INSERT MAX+1 query?

Tags: mysql, insert, syntax-error

I'm having problem with this query:

`INSERT INTO invoices(invuid, linenumber) VALUES (?, SELECT(SELECT max(linenumber)+1 FROM invoices WHERE invuid=?))`

It keeps saying: `"General error: 1093 You can't specify target table 'invoices' for update"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is invalid, use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` and remove the `values` part like this:

```
INSERT INTO invoices(invuid, linenumber) 
SELECT ?, max(linenumber)+1 FROM invoices WHERE invuid=?
```